# why my code isn't working in discord py library?

Tags: discord.py

I want to send DM message when user will join in my server, but when user react to emoji it isn't working.
Here is code:

```
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".", intents = intents)

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    message = await member.send(f"{member.name}")
    emoji = "✅"
    emoji_1 = "❌"
    await message.add_reaction(emoji)
    await message.add_reaction(emoji_1)

    def check(reaction, user):
        return reaction.message == message and str(reaction) == emoji and str(reaction) == emoji_1 and user == member.name


    react, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check)
    if react.emoji == emoji_1:
        await message.delete()
    elif react.emoji == "✅":
        await member.send("hello")
```

Comment: "why my code isn't working in discord py library?" -- you tell me, why is it not working?

Comment: I don't know why it isn't working, that's why I write this question here.

Comment: The meaning of @ŁukaszKwieciński's comment was that we need to know what your error is. WHAT does not work? Do you get a specific error? Or does the bot not start? We cannot magically look at your code and tell you whats wrong

Comment: I didn't getting errors from terminal, when i reacting on emoji, bot didn't respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a logic error inside your `check` function, you can only react with **one** emoji at a time, so this:

```py
str(reaction) == emoji and str(reaction) == emoji_1
```

doesn't make much sense, you're looking for the `or` logic operator:

```py
str(reaction) == emoji or str(reaction) == emoji_1
```